# iphone App crashes while Parsing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parsing, nsxmlparser, nsurl

my app is crashed as it execute [NSXMLParser parse]; statement,and
i am getting following :

2011-03-01 09:36:31.735 MasterApp[228:207] -[NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f6b000
2011-03-01 09:36:31.738 MasterApp[228:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f6b000'

*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0252eb99 **exceptionPreprocess + 185

    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0267e40e objc_exception_throw + 47

    2   CoreFoundation                      0x025306ab -[NSObject(NSObject)   doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187

    3   CoreFoundation                      0x024a02b6 __*forwarding*** + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0249fe72 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   Foundation                          0x00114afc -[NSXMLParser parse] + 147
    6   MasterApp                           0x0000c731 -[identifierList getUrl] + 994
    7   MasterApp                           0x0000c306 -[identifierList   actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:] + 56
    8   UIKit                               0x0077047d -[UIActionSheet(Private)   _buttonClicked:] + 258
    9   UIKit                               0x002dc7f8 -[UIApplication   sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    10  UIKit                               0x00367de0 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    11  UIKit                               0x0036a262 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    12  UIKit                               0x00368e0f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    13  UIKit                               0x003003d0 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    14  UIKit                               0x002e1cb4 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    15  UIKit                               0x002e69bf _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7672
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x02d8a822 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0250fff4 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 52
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x02470807 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0246da93 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0246d350 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0246d271 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x02d8900c GSEventRunModal + 217
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x02d890d1 GSEventRun + 115
    24  UIKit                               0x002eaaf2 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    25  MasterApp                           0x00001dbc main + 102
    26  MasterApp                           0x00001d4d start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.

thank you in advance

Comment: Just throwing usual advice: this sounds like missing retain somewhere.

Comment: thank u for reply, i analysis my code but retain is not case ...still confuse  where is the problem

Comment: Can you add the piece of code you use to parse? It seems like you are sending a message (calling  method) which is not recognized by the object you send it to...

Comment: @MiKL, following is code also i am using synchronous NSURL -- NSError *error;  
NSURLResponse *response;  
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req   returningResponse:&response error:&error];  
webData =[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  
 
if (xmlParser)
{
   [xmlParser release];
 }    
xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:webData]; [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
 [xmlParser setDelegate: self];
 [xmlParser parse];

Comment: @MiKL, i just try to use "urlData" instead of webData in  xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:urlData]; and now it parse very well ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just try to use "urlData" instead of webData in xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:urlData]; and now it parse very well